# How to solve the address issue if I restart an external service inside python with flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am using flask to build a python web service, for example, I set the flask port as 8080 like this:

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def data_construct():
    os.system('sh restart.sh')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

and the `restart.sh` is used for restarting an external service, but after I send a HTTP POST request to `/data`, the restart is successfully completed, but after a while, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hello.py", line 87, in <module>
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
File "/home/work/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 739, in run
   run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
File "/home/work/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 613, in run_simple
   test_socket.bind((hostname, port))
File "/home/work/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
  return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

the 'restart.sh' is like this (storage is a C++-complied program):

```
killall storage
nohup ./storage &
```

and I find the external service is starting using the port `8080` which it is not supposed to do (its original port is still in use), how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have some code for the external service?

Comment: I don't have the orignal code... since it is complied, it is not readable...

Comment: Where does python fit in if `storage` is a compiled c++ program? Are you sure it is python that is holding onto the port?

Comment: Why not run your flask app on a different port?

Comment: `storage` is used for reloading data, and its default port is 8042.  python should listen to port 8080 since I set it in the script, right?

Comment: okay, I will change to another port, but I am afraid `storage` will take that port too...